# How to call mDrawerLayout from MyActivity1 to another activity eg VideoPlayerActivity

Tags: java, android, vlc, layout-inflater, drawerlayout

Can Anyone here please explain in a simple way that a beginner can understand or edit this code as an example...
What I want is call my DrawerLayout that I have created in MyActivity1 as follow...

MyActivity1

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, listArray));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            openActivity(position);
        }
    });

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                       /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,     /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.open_drawer,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.close_drawer)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


    /**
     * As we are calling BaseActivity from manifest file and this base activity is intended just to add navigation drawer in our app.
     * We have to open some activity with layout on launch. So we are checking if this BaseActivity is called first time then we are opening our first activity.
     * */
    if(isLaunch){
        /**
         *Setting this flag false so that next time it will not open our first activity.
         *We have to use this flag because we are using this BaseActivity as parent activity to our other activity.
         *In this case this base activity will always be call when any child activity will launch.
         */
        isLaunch = false;
        openActivity(0);
    }
}

/**
 * @param position
 *
 * Launching activity when any list item is clicked.
 */
protected void openActivity(int position) {

    /**
     * We can set title & itemChecked here but as this BaseActivity is parent for other activity,
     * So whenever any activity is going to launch this BaseActivity is also going to be called and
     * it will reset this value because of initialization in onCreate method.
     * So that we are setting this in child activity.
     */

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Item1Activity.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Item2Activity.class));
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Item3Activity.class));
            break;
        case 3:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Item4Activity.class));
            break;
        case 4:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Item5Activity.class));
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }else {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}

private void openDrawer(){
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }else {

        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        openDrawer();

    }else if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1){
        openDrawer();
    }else if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT){
        openDrawer();
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

VideoPlayerActivity from Github as Example.

and call it here in this activity  [link here](https://github.com/tianshaokai/vlc-android/blob/master/vlc-android/src/org/videolan/vlc/gui/video/VideoPlayerActivity.java)  (Vlc VideoPlayerActivity ).
I hardly see any example since most of them are totally efferent. eg it call another activity inside a drawer and vice-versa, but what I want is simply call the Drawer inside that class, which I believe its simple but I failed after many attempts, I always end up with error or drawer not opening.

Comment: Why is this question down voted already?

Comment: Come on stackoverflow community no one knows? :XD